# Javascript var query returning [object Object]

Tags: javascript, json, sharepoint-2010

I've got a JavaScript file which is querying a SharePoint list. I'm querying two drop down lists. The first - LifeCycleStatus - comes back fine, but the Priority drop down comes back with [screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxRkE.png) [object OBJECT]. I think it has to do with the var query string. I've added the 'Priority' column to the var query but it doesn't seem to be making any difference

```
var query = "http://collaboration- 
   de.vxxx.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?$expand=LifeCycleStatus&Priority&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + "";
```

Full JavaScript below:

```
function getDeviceDetails() {
var txtTitle = "";
var txtOverview = "";
var txtAccessories = "";
var txtDevicetype = "";
var txtTypicalDeviceUsage ="";
var txtKnownSystemIssues ="";
var txtLifeCycles = "";
var txtTrafficlight = "";
    var tempLCS2 = "";

var query = "http://collaboration-dev.xxx/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?$expand=LifeCycleStatus&Priority&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + "";
    var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        var tempID = item.Id;
        var tempTitle = item.Title;




         var LifeCycleStart = item.DeviceAvailableFrom;



        var LifeCycleStatus = item.LifeCycleStatusValue;
        var DeviceOverView = item.Description;
        var AccessDetails = item.Accessories;
        var DeviceKind = item.Devicetype;
        var Usage = item.TypicalUsage;
        var DevicePriority = item.Priority;


        txtTitle = "<p>" + LifeCycleStart + "</p><p>" + LifeCycleStatus + "</p>";
        txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
        txtAccessories = "<p>" + AccessDetails + "</p>";  
        txtDevicetype = "<p>" + DeviceKind  + "</p>";
        txtTypicalDeviceUsage = "<p>" + Usage + "</p>";
        txtTrafficlight = "<p>" + DevicePriority + "</p>";
       // txtKnownSystemIssues = "<p>" + KnownSystem + "</p>"
    });
    $('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle));  
    $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));
    $('#devicekind').append(txtDevicetype);
    $('#deviceacc').append(txtAccessories);
    $('#deviceuse').append(txtTypicalDeviceUsage);
    $('#devicestatus').append(txtTrafficlight);

});





call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

}

Comment: Because the fetched value is an Object and when you try to convert object to string, its done using `.toString` method which returns `[object Object]`

Comment: That's odd cause it's returning the LifeCycleStatus drop down column results fine?

Comment: What would you suggest Rajesh?

Comment: Log the value and access correct property

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means

Comment: In the REST query you are selecting LifeCycleStatus and Priority. From the returned item, you are using LifeCycleStatus**Value** and Priority. Is there a "PriorityValue"?

Comment: BOOM! Thanks @JanErikGunnar that worked. I added Value to item.Priority and it's showing, but I'm still not quite sure why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Priority" and "LifeCycleStatus" contains an object. You can use the debugger/console to see what the object is - I bet it contains a string with the Value, and the internal ID of the value, possibly other things. Converting an object to a string returns "[object Object]".

"Priority**Value**" and "LifeCycleStatus**Value**" are probably shorthands to the value string.